# XML::LibXML with default namespaces

Tags: excel, perl, xml-parsing

I have an XML file as follows

#### example.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Workbook xmlns='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet'>
    <id>test</id>
</Workbook>
```

The following code does not find the `id` tag value:

```
use XML::LibXML;

my $filename = 'example.xml';

my $dom = XML::LibXML->load_xml( location => $filename );
my $xpc = XML::LibXML::XPathContext->new($dom);
my $match1 = $xpc->findnodes('//id');

print "XPath $match1\n";
```

But if I remove the default namespace definition and replace it with this line:

```
<Workbook>
```

Then it works.

How do read the tags with the default namespace defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to register the namespace.

```
my $xml = q[<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Workbook xmlns='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet'>
    <id>test</id>
</Workbook>];

use XML::LibXML;

my $filename = 'example.xml';

my $dom = XML::LibXML->load_xml( string => $xml );
my $xpc = XML::LibXML::XPathContext->new($dom);
$xpc->registerNs('x', 'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet');
my $match1 = $xpc->findnodes('//x:id');

print "XPath $match1\n";
```

Or you may use this if you do not want to registrer the namespace:

```
my $dom = XML::LibXML->load_xml( string => $xml );
my $xpc = XML::LibXML::XPathContext->new($dom);

my $match2 = $xpc->findnodes("//*[name()='id']");

print "XPath $match2\n";
```

Comment: I have another question pertaining to namespaces that I am trying to solve that you might also be able to help with. Should I create another question for that?

Comment: I have no URN but a https:// URL can _I use this too or do _I have to convert it?

Answer (score 3):

There are two things you need to know here

- The namespace prefix used in the XML does not need to match any prefixes used in XPath queries; only the corresponding URN needs to be the same
- There is no way to define a "default" namespace within XPath

That means the namespace declared in the XML without a prefix must be given a prefix in XPath expressions

This code looks correct, but I am not in a position to test it at present. Please make sure to *always* `use strict` and `use warnings 'all'` at the top of every Perl program you write

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use XML::LibXML;

my $filename = 'example.xml';

my $dom = XML::LibXML->load_xml( location => $filename );
my $xpc = XML::LibXML::XPathContext->new( $dom );
$xpc->registerNs( mss => 'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet' );
my $match1 = $xpc->findnodes('//mss:id');

print "XPath $match1\n";
```